# javascript Date different days equal milliseconds

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/skowron_line/zPCBc/1/

```
var d1 = '31.05.2012';
var d2 = '01.06.2012';

var s1 = d1.split('.');
var s2 = d2.split('.');

var nd1 = new Date(s1[2], s1[1], s1[0]);
var nd2 = new Date(s2[2], s2[1], s2[0]);

$('#a').html(s1 + ' - '+ s2 +' = '+ nd2.getTime() +' - '+ nd1.getTime());

$('#b').html(
nd1.getFullYear() +'-'+ nd1.getMonth() +'-'+ nd1.getDate() +'<br />'+ nd2.getFullYear() +'-'+ nd2.getMonth() +'-'+ nd2.getDate()
);
```

​
Can someone explain my what is wrong with this code ??. Why `31.05.2012` i equal to `01.06.2012`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript months are 0-based, so month 05 is actually June. Since there's no June 31st, JS is adjusting the date to be July (js month 06) 1st.

The new date code should be:

```
var nd1 = new Date(s1[2], parseInt(s1[1])-1, s1[0]);
```

Comment: I know but now its http://jsfiddle.net/skowron_line/zPCBc/3/ `2012-4-31` and `2012-5-1` and its not what I want

Comment: Since when have there been 31 days in April? April in Javascript is month 3.

Comment: Ok now i know what U mean. Stupid me

Comment: But why in secound DIV displays both `2012-6-1` ??

Comment: Why not? "June 31st" is an impossible date (in internal JS values, 31/05/12), so Js compensates by making it valid. `31-1/05+1/12 -> 1/6/12`. July 1st (JS month #6) is perfectly valid, so that doesn't get changed.